# Web-pack successfully compiled but does not show output in browser

Tags: reactjs, redux, webpack-dev-server

Browser http://localhost:8080 still says

This page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: We need more information to solve your problem.  What does your webpack configuration look like?  How is your server set up?  What steps have you taken to try to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using webpack, please check what parameters you have used in devserver tag of your webpack.config.js file.
It should be as below:

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './src', 
    port: 3000
},
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, it was taking default port 8080 so adding port in devserver works fine .